# Creating new records with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, has-many

I am trying to create simple form to create valuations (offers) for specific goods( exactly spare arts). Valuation may have many parts which are selected using select form. I am using  classes listed below. I have also created join table valuation_lines to store valuations.
When using the form there are no errors but records are missing...
Unfortunatelly I got stuck and have no idea how to properly create form to save records in valuation_lines table?

I will appreciate any help on this issue! As I am new to rails I got stuck for two days on this and have no idea how to overcome this...

```
class Valuation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :valuation_lines
    has_many :parts, :through => :valuation_lines
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
end

class ValuationLine < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :part
    belongs_to :valuation
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :valuation_lines
    has_many :valuations, :through => :valuation_lines
end
```

Further my form for creating new valuations looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@valuation) do |f| %>
  <% if @valuation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@valuation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this valuation from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @valuation.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :part do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.label :part %><br>   
      <%= builder.collection_select :part_id, Part.all, :id, :name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

join table:

```
 create_table "valuation_lines", force: true do |t|
        t.integer "valuation_id"
        t.integer "part_id"
        t.integer "pruchase_price"
      end
```

valuation controller:

```
 # GET /valuations/new
  def new
    @valuation = Valuation.new
  end

   # POST /valuations
  # POST /valuations.json
  def create
    @valuation = Valuation.new(valuation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @valuation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Valuation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @valuation }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @valuation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Your `f.fields_for :valuation` doesn't look right. You already have a `form_for(@valuation)`. I would expect, within that, you'd have a `f.fields_for :part` within which you would allow `Part` attributes. In your model `Valuation`, you would also need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts`. If you do a Google search on "rails nested forms" you'll find some good information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for a reply. I've applied your input but still doesnt work... :( Any other hints?

Comment: If you've changed your code, then you might want to update your problem since I don't know exactly what you did. You might also want to show the Valuation#create and Valuation#new controller methods. If something doesn't work, make sure you indicate clearly what that means (error messages? no results? erroneous results? etc).

Comment: I've just updated the code in the questions according to your advice. "doesn't work" means no result i.e. it creates new valuation but doesn't doesn't create new records in valuation_lines and doesn't show any error. To make it more clear i've put this on https://github.com/macieekh/dealflow

Comment: I don't see where you're creating a part for the valuation that your view pertains to. Your view would show a collection of available parts (if there are any). If there are none, then none will be shown. And when you hit submit, no new ones would be created since there's no code there to create one. You should try the suggested Google search I mentioned. There's some good info out there on nested forms. In particular, checkout railscasts.com.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to create any parts in this view! User should be able only to select which part he want to put in the valuation. At this moment to simplify I print only one part and can't figure out how to put this part's id in the valuation_line table in the part_id field...

Comment: When you do create a part for a valuation (where ever you are doing it) Rails should automatically udpate the `valuation_lines` table for you with the correct IDs. That's assuming you create the record properly.